# Transfer table that contains Images from One Database server to another Database Server Sql Server 2008, C#.net windows Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to transfer sql server table that contain image field from local server to VPS server which is located at remote location. i write parameterized query for this purpose and its working. My problem is that it is working very slow as it is depend on network speed. is there any other way to transfer image table.

Comment: One method is : create SQL script for it and create ZIP file for it, upload it on server, unzip and run directly on server. directly running on internet will always depend on internet speed.

Comment: Is this something you have to do again and again automatically (how often) or rather something to be done now and then? How big is the transfer amount?

Comment: Also, try using BCP tool.

Comment: @par : Thanks  for your replay i have tried this but i want to transfer this by using application only i don't want developer or DBA will interfere after application is developed

Comment: @Shnugo : Thanks for your replay, my average row size is 200 kb per record

Comment: Well, 200kb is not that much... How many records and how often do you have to transfer? Are the servers reaching each other ("linked servers") or do you really have to transfer your data in file format?